# Building workspace in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

When I open the eclipse IDE, after building workspace upto 70%, IDE suddenly closes. When open the eclipse ide path, I got the error log file printed, as hs_err_pid3604.log

hs_err_pid3604.log file details

> An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
>
> Internal Error (4E4D4554484F440E435050071F), pid=4052, tid=2236
>
> Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (1.6.0-b105 mixed mode)  If you
>   would like to submit a bug report, please visit:

Not getting why this is happening, how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you see any stacktrace? Can you launch eclipse with -clean option and disable any plugin that could be causing a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.6.0-b105 is a very old version of java (I found some references to it from 2006 posts…), you should probably try first with an up-to-date, or at least more recent version. Filing a bug for such an old version would not make sense if it cannot be reproduced on recent versions.

If it still does not work, try to cleanup eclipse by running it with `-clean` parameter from the command line.

Comment: Good point, even if you are staying with Java 6, get the most recent version of that.

Comment: Actually its problem with running old version of java, took update and its worked fine, thanks to all, for your valuable replies.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens because of a bug in the Java VM (or something possibly wrong with Eclipse SWT). Usually these are not reproducible. If you get it consistently, file a bug at eclipse.org and they can help there.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the memory and try?

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini